# Auto populating basic list form without info path

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

We want to auto populate a basic list form but can't use info path and working on sharepoint foundation, can someone point all available options pelase.

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward approach would be to use jQuery (or the SP.Services library). You would open the newform.aspx in SharePoint designer, include references to the jQuery libraries, and then write your specific javascript code when the form loads to do your prepopulation of the HTML controls that SharePoint renders. Take a look at http://sympmarc.com/2010/10/08/using-jquery-to-prefill-and-disable-required-column-in-a-sharepoint-form/comment-page-2/ for a short example to get you started.